# How to launch settings/defaultapp window programatically on Windows 8/8.1?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8, windows-8.1

Is there any alternative to [Launching Settings App programmatically on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app) for Windows 8/8.1?

I need to launch the App Defaults page on a Windows 8/8.1 machine. On Windows 10, I do this:

```cs
bool result = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:privacy-webcam"));
```

I could not find an alternative for Windows 8 yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: The doc says **IApplicationActivationManager** is supported by Windows 8 (I cannot test). On Windows 10, to launch the App Defaults  page, I use  L"page=SettingsPageAppsDefaults"
  L"&target=SettingsPageAppsDefaultsDefaultAppsListView" as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [canonical Control Panel item names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/controlpanel-canonical-names#default-programs) on Vista to 8.1:

You can use [IOpenControlPanel::Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-iopencontrolpanel-open) or execute control.exe:

```
%systemroot%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram
```

Windows XP and older only [supports a handful of items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/executing-control-panel-items#legacy-control-panel-commands) and they use the old style names.

The Settings app on Windows 8 can be started with this hack:

```
Explorer.exe shell:AppsFolder\Windows.ImmersiveControlPanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

but I'm not sure if there is a way to open a specific page.